# bootstrap.js:441 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap, bootstrap-carousel

I am Using Angular bootstrap. Actually, there are two Carousel slider in same page so some time Carousel get stopped when getting this error.

Please see attached image to check error what i am getting.[image]

The scenario is i am trying to get data from google and when it loads, sometime my carousel stopped so is this happening because i am using very old version of Bootstrap and jQuery? or there is some other mistake?

Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *CarouselModule* from ngx-bootstrap: [Carousel](https://ngx-bootstrap-latest.surge.sh/#/carousel)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help so i will try to use it and will let you know if it is working for me or not.

Comment: your link is not working, can you please suggest me any other one?